# Ice Faces 3 page cannot open in ie 9

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-9, icefaces

I am working on a JSF application using Ice faces 3, tomcat 7.0. My problem is that the application runs fine on firefox and chrome but doesnot open in Internet explorer 9. It doesnot throw any error just the page comes blank white on ie.
This is the xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"[
     <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
     <!ENTITY auml   "&#228;">
     <!ENTITY ouml   "&#246;">
     <!ENTITY Ouml   "&#214;">
     <!ENTITY uuml   "&#252;"> 
     <!ENTITY szlig  "&#223;">
]>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"  xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"   xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component" 
    >
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>#{msgs.MyTitle}</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/tas.css" />
    <ice:outputStyle href="./css/processbar.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" language="javascript" src="posadmin.js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <ice:panelGrid columns="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        ***<ui:include src="head.xhtml"/>
                <ui:include src="Filter.xhtml"/>
        <ui:include src="admin.xhtml"/>*** 
        </ice:panelGrid>
     <ice:form id="error_form">
    <ui:include src="/popups/error.xhtml"></ui:include>
  </ice:form>
  <ice:form id="message_form">
    <ui:include src="/popups/message.xhtml"></ui:include>
  </ice:form>
    <ice:form id="close_form">
    <ui:include src="/popups/close.xhtml"></ui:include>
  </ice:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I remove any one of ui:include statements

```
<ui:include src="head.xhtml"/>
<ui:include src="Filter.xhtml"/> or
<ui:include src="admin.xhtml"/>
```

above and I remove all the ice:form blocks the page gets displayed on ie 9...
can anyone help me on this please????

Comment: Browser specific rendering errors are not necessarily caused by JSF, but by the HTML/CSS/JS code it generates. You should try to obtain a raw copy of the generated HTML/CSS/JS code (open page in browser, rightclick, view source, download, etc) and then try to eliminate as many as possible parts while the problem still exhibits. Finally repost and retarget the question to HTML/CSS experts (not necessarily JSF experts). Once you get the answer, trackback the cause into the JSF code and fix it in there accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the javax.faces.jar (mojarra) in the classpath from your application.
This jar comes with Icefaces Libs

Try this out.